# Troubleshooting GeoServer Vector Tile TIME VIEWPARAMS Misinterpretation in Mapbox GL JS Integration

Tags: postgis, geoserver, vector-tiles, time-series, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to deploy a spatial layer with data in **PostgreSQL/PostGIS**. The data has a temporal dimension and is configured as such in **GeoServer**.

The goal is to use the layer through **Mapbox GL JS** and to develop a temporal navigator that can animate each of the 168 time steps of the layer using the `datetime` field. He is a screenshot of my proof of concept:

[image: Screenshot of the final visual]

The layer was created in **GeoServer** using the SQL View concept. It involves an SQL query where the `datetime` field is used to vary the time step we want to display. The `%TIME%` variable has been declared as a `View Parameter`. Here an example of the SQL I setup:

```
SELECT geom, value FROM my_table WHERE datetime = '%TIME%'
```

Using the temporal navigator (slider) via the UI (HTML), the user stops at a given time step, and this time step is passed via `VIEWPARAMS`

```
e.g., &VIEWPARAMS=TIME:2023-01-01T12:00:00Z
```

This works very well for a `WMS layer`.

My problem arises when I try to use my data in the context where the format of the WMS is not a `PNG` but `application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile`. To support this format in **GeoServer**, I previously installed the `Vector Tiles extension`. Still aiming to use this format from the extension, I configured the `Tile Caching/Parameter Filters` section. Indeed, I added `VIEWPARAMS` as a filter parameter.

[image: screenshot of the Parameter Filters under Tile Caching of my layer under Geoserver]

The URL I configured in **Mapbox** to access my data in vector tile format is:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/my-workspace:wave_layer@EPSG:900913@geojson/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?VIEWPARAMS=TIME:${timeParamVal}
```

where `${timeParamVal}` can vary within the 168 forecast hours depending on the value from the temporal slider.

**The bug:**
In this context, when **GeoServer** receives the request, it systematically removes the TIME portion and tries to interpret the date as follows:

```
Extract from the GeoServer log:
ViewParams = [{2023-10-19T06=00:00.000Z}]
```

As you can see the ViewParams is misinterpreted. He completely removed the TIME portion, retaining only the date. He then interprets the date and time as being (`param=2023-10-19T06`) (`value=00:00.000Z`).

Normally, I should have seen here:

```
ViewParams = [{TIME:2023-10-19T06:00:00.000Z}]
```

Here is the browser request:

[image]

Here is the full request as received and logged into Geoserver :

```
Request: getMap
        Angle = 0.0
        BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
        Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-1.377578698375E7 : -1.375621910451172E7, 6261721.356249999 : 6281289.235488281]
        BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
        Buffer = 0
        Clip = null
        CQLFilter = null
        Crs = PROJCS["WGS84 / Google Mercator",
  GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST],
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
  PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0],
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0],
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0],
  UNIT["m", 1.0],
  AXIS["x", EAST],
  AXIS["y", NORTH],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]
        Elevation = []
        Env = {}
        Exceptions = SE_XML
        FeatureId = null
        FeatureVersion = null
        Filter = null
        Format = application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile
        FormatOptions = {}
        Get = true
        Height = 256
        Interpolations = []
        Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@1b6789a2]
        MaxFeatures = null
        Palette = null
        RawKvp = {FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile, STYLES=generic, WIDTH=256, HEIGHT=256, LAYERS=my-workspace:wave_layer, EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:900913, BBOX=-13775786.98375,6261721.356249999,-13756219.10451172,6281289.235488281, VIEWPARAMS=2023-10-19T06:00:00.000Z, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true}
        RemoteOwsType = null
        RemoteOwsURL = null
        Request = GetMap
        RequestCharset = UTF-8
        ScaleMethod = null
        Sld = null
        SldBody = null
        SldVersion = null
        SortBy = null
        SortByArrays = null
        SRS = EPSG:900913
        StartIndex = null
        StyleBody = null
        StyleFormat = sld
        Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=generic]]
        StyleUrl = null
        StyleVersion = null
        Tiled = false
        TilesOrigin = null
        Time = [null]
        Transparent = true
        ValidateSchema = false
        Version = 1.1.1
        ViewParams = [{2023-10-19T06=00:00.000Z}]
        Width = 256
```

Due to this misinterpretation of the `VIEWPARAMS`, the default value configured in the `SQL View` is used to generate the content of the data to be returned in vector tile format. The reason is simple, `TIME` does not arrive in the `SQL View` as a `Variable parameter` and it is the default value that is favored and not the one from the slider.
In the end, no matter the value of the slider, the data returned by the **GeoServer** server is always that of the same time step, the default one.

How could I correct my situation?

In your opinion, where does the problem lie?

Is it a misconfiguration on my part?

I suspect the `Tile Caching/Parameter Filters` section in the **GeoServer** configuration might be a source of the problem.

Comment: Does GeoServer actually recieve the correct request? Check what the browser is requesting, and add that to the question.

Comment: The full resquest log as received by Geoserver is now in the question. Thanks @alphabetasoup!

Comment: Does it need to escape `:` characters in the value? It does do some separation on the `:` character to distinguish the parameter and value in `TIME:2023...`, and then seems to trip up on the second one.